# Configure Apache/Tomcat for large number of webapps

Tags: apache, tomcat, permgen, catalina.out

The most common error we receive in catalina.out is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

We have web services installed that requires up to 100 Tomcat webapps be started and run all at the same time.  Docs indicate we should allocate up to 128MB of RAM for each running Webapp.  We have tried multiple Tomcat installations and a single installation (all on same server) but either the CPU is maxed out at startup OR RAM is exhausted.

I've modified the setenv.sh file to set some startup options which have helped, but we are still unable to get all 100 webapps running reliably. Here is what I have in our setenv.sh file:

```
JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -d64 -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m "
export JAVA_OPTS;
```

Server specs vary, but all are at least:

- Solaris 11 x86 (Unix) VMs (VMware)
- 8GB RAM Minimum
- 2 CPUs Minimum (some have four)

There is plenty of disk space.

Comment: "up to 128MB" (I assume you mean PermGen) is very unspecific - it really depends on the app(s) in question. For some of our apps 256 MB has turned out to be insufficient, so we're using 384 MB. 384 x 100 > 8 GB however - and that is just PermGen...

Are you able to upgrade to Java 8, which by default autoincreases Metaspace (former PermGen) to see if the servers can cope?

Comment: We are updating to Java 8 soon so perhaps that may help.  The vendor for the web services web apps has not provided any scaling information as most of their clients only use a couple installations.  We are servicing all of Ohio so we have to figure out how to run 100 of these apps with docs that are good for 3 apps.  Thank you for the info.  I have also scheduled a call with the vendor.